# Create & Alter Schema Permissions for a Login role in Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql database with 3 Schemas (2 user defined and 1 public).

I have script that takes backup of the user defined schema's and then drops the schema's.

Now after doing some operations I want to restore the user defined schemas from the schema backup(schema_backup.out).

When I execute

```
cat schema_backup.out | psql xx_db_name_xx
```

I am getting the following error message

```
ERROR:  permission denied for database xx_db_name_xx
ERROR:  schema "aaaa" does not exist 
ERROR:  permission denied for database xx_db_name_xx
ERROR:  schema "bbbb" does not exist 
ERROR:  must be owner of database xx_db_name_xx
```

When I execute the same command as Admin user its executing just fine.
But, when I execute as a 'xxxxxx' user its failing.

Can someone guide me, what permissions/rights should be added to 'xxxxxx' to restore the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres already answered this for you: `ERROR:`***`must be owner of database`***`xx_db_name_xx`.

You need to `ALTER` the `DATABASE` and `SET OWNER` to be the user you're trying to make schema changes as.
([See the Postgres manual for information on the `ALTER DATABASE` SQL Statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdatabase.html))

---

Generally it's easier to restore databases as the Postgres superuser - This avoids any permissions issues, and normally ownership/permissions are restored when you restore the database.

Comment: Hi 
Thankyou for the details, I am trying to using psql and get it it done something like 

cat xxx.out | psql -d "xx_db_name_xx" -U "db_user"

and its failing.

Comment: @Trip If you haven't already done so you should probably spend some quality time with [the Backup & Restore section of the Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup.html)